# Error while using sqlalchemy in AWS lambda to load data into Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load pandas Dataframe into Redshift table using below code.

```
#PYTHON 3.8#
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sq  
url = sq.engine.url.URL.create(
        drivername='redshift+redshift_connector', # indicate 
        redshift_connector driver and dialect will be used
        host=f"{redshift_endpoint}", # Amazon Redshift host
        port=5439, # Amazon Redshift port
        database='dev', # Amazon Redshift database
        username=f"{redshift_db_user}", # Amazon Redshift username
        password=f"{redshift_db_password}" # Amazon Redshift password
    )
print('Connection URL is',url)
engine=sq.create_engine(url)
cnn = engine.connect()
```

I am getting below error while creation of engine.

```
>[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.util' has no attribute 'text_type'
>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 44, in lambda_handler
    cnn = engine.connect()
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3268, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 170, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 914, in __connect
    pool.dispatch.connect.for_modify(
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 473, in _exec_w_sync_on_first_run
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 487, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 704, in on_connect
    do_on_connect(dbapi_connection)
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy_redshift/dialect.py", line 1395, in on_connect
    fn(conn)
  File "/opt/python/sqlalchemy_redshift/dialect.py", line 1373, in on_connect
    conn.py_types[quoted_name] = conn.py_types[util.text_type]
```

I have used SQLalchmy and redshift_connector for creating connection.
Please let me know what am I doing incorrectly.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I have added the Traceback error message.

Comment: maybe `sqlalchemy_redshift` needs newer or older version of  `sqlalchemy`. You may find source code for the newest `sqlalchemy` and check if it has `util.text_type`

Comment: Yes it was version compatibility issue. sqlalchemy_redshift uses older version of sqlalchemy. Thanks.

Comment: You could put this information as answer below - you could put what version you needed. It can be useful for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused due version compatibility between `sqlalchemy_redshift` and `sqlalchemy`. I had installed version 2.0.23 of `sqlalchemy` but `sqlalchemy_redshift` uses version 1.4.50. We do not have to explicitly install `sqlalchemy` because it's compatible version gets installed with `sqlalchemy_redshift` as a dependency.